# Python Binary Search Tree Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, binary-search

```
#BST
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left = None, right = None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def search(root, k):
    if root is None or root.val == k:
        return root
    elif root.val < k:
        return search(root.right, k)
    else:
        return search(root.left, k)

def minimum(root):
    if root is None or root.left is None:
        return root
    return minimum(root.left)

def maximum(root):
    if root is None or root.right is None:
        return root
    return maximum(root.right)

def successor(root, node):
    if node.right is not None:
        return minimum(node.right)
    succ = None
    while root is not None and root.val != node.val:
        if root.val > node.val:
            succ = root
            root = root.left
        else:
            root = root.right
    return succ

def predecessor(root, node):
    if node.left is not None:
        return maximum(node.left)
    else:
        pred = None
        while root is not None and root.val != node.val:
            if root.val > node.val:
                root = root.left
            else:
                pred = root
                root = root.right
        return pred

def insert(root, key):
    if root is None:
        return Node(key)
    elif root.val < key:
        return Node(root.val, root.left, insert(root.right, key))
    else:
        return Node(root.val, insert(root.left, key), root.right)

def parent(root, node):
    if root is None:
        return root
    elif (root.left is not None and root.left.val == node.val) or \
         (root.right is not None and root.right.val == node.val):
        return root
    else:
        if root.val < node.val:
            return parent(root.right, node)
        else:
            return parent(root.left, node)

def delete(root, node):
    p = parent(root, node)
    if node.left is None or node.right is None:
        replacement = node.left if node.left is None else node.right
        if p is None:
            root = replacement
        elif p.val < node.val:
            p.right = replacement
        else:
            p.left = replacement
    else:
        replacement = successor(root, node)
        succ_parent = parent(root, replacement)
        succ_parent.left = replacement.right
        node.val = replacement.val
    return root
```

Require code review in terms of correctness, style consistency, efficiency, code readability, and "pythonic"ness. (I, of course, welcome any other comments on the code as well)

I know that this a bit big to review completely. Reviewing only one or more methods will be appreciated.

Also, the [WikiPage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) talks about designing persistent data structures. When should one consider such design and what are the advantages?

Github: https://github.com/abhisheksp/algorithms
(the repo has the test cases)

Comment: short gripe: `if not None` is very redundant. None type in python has a truthy value of false. You can jut say  `if root.right:` and the code will then execute if it exists, and will not if it doesn't. This alone will make your code much more readable.

Comment: @Erich I feel that explicit "is None" comparison is more readable.
Even the PEP style guide recommends that.
Source: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/comparison_to_none.html

Comment: Is there a reason you can't save the parent of a node and update it as it changes?

Answer (score 4):

## docstrings

Docstrings matter. Delete the cryptic `#BST` comment and spell it out in a PEP8 class docstring:

```
class Node:
"""Implements a Binary Search Tree."""
```

Either `search` or `__init__` needs a docstring that mentions the equality case (I'm looking at `elif root.val < k:`, as opposed to `<= k`).

## correctness

I can't imagine `successor` is correct. You didn't offer any unit tests like this, but I'm thinking of passing in a node with no right subtree, a node having the same value as root. Then we return None ?? This comes back to the `<= k` detail I mentioned above. Anyway, `predecessor` is nicely parallel, simple is good. And `insert` is beautiful and concise.

## public API design

For some methods, rather than passing in `root`, it would be more natural to be working with an instance of your BST class, with `self.root` implicitly available.

## style

As a trivial style detail, in `parent` you might use parentheses a level deeper to remove the backslash.

I didn't run `flake8` myself, but overall it looks good. I have a weak preference for `if node.left:` instead of `if node.left is not None:`.

## tests

I'm looking at this:

```
class BSTTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_recursive_search(self):
        root  = build_bst()
        actual = search(root, 35).val
        expected = 35
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

I would much rather see the method expressed concisely:

```
    def test_recursive_search(self):
        root  = build_bst()
        self.assertEqual(35, search(root, 35).val)
```

It might even come out as:

```
    def test_recursive_search(self):
        self.assertEqual(35, search(self.root, 35).val)
```

where `build_bst()` is invoked by a setup method.

There are other tests, e.g. `test_insert_on_empty_tree`, where of course hanging on to an `actual` temp variable is the natural way to express it.

I am very glad to see these tests. They appear to give reasonable code coverage.

Another example tree that stores multiple copies of a given value (e.g. 30) would be of interest.

## summary

Overall it looks good! Ship it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for sharing your code,

Instead of dealing with nodes directly, I think it would be easier, and make a lot more sense to have code that looked like this.

```
bst = BST([1,6,3,3,5])
bst.insert(5)
min = bst.minimum()
max = bst.max()
```

etc.

the `BST` class would be in charge of managing the `Node` objects. This way I'm not passing around a root `Node` to all my functions. For someone who wants to use this tree, I shouldn't need to know about how all these `Node`s work. A `Node` is an implementation detail of your `BST`

Make use of `__eq__`, `__hash__`and `__str__`. Implementing these methods would allow you to compare and display your `Node`objects very easily. You could also implement `__lt__` and `__gt__` to compare nodes via `node1 < node2` rather than `node1.val < node2.val` (although `__gt__` may not actually be required here)

very small stylistic thing here. The code `left = None, right = None` should be `left=None, right=None` (no spaces) according to PEP8 guidelines.

Some additional methods you could add

```
post_order_traversal
pre_order_traversal
in_order_traversal
```

these could maybe just print the elements in the given order, or maybe return a list of the elements (not the nodes) in that order.

Overall I think it's looking very nice!

Keep it up

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for persistence.

You can temporarily instrument your code like

```
def __init__(self, val, left = None, right = None):
    print("new", self.val, self)
    ...

def __del__(self):
    print("del", self.val, self)
```

to get an idea what is going on whe you are inserting nodes.
Your tree is not persistent as nodes are deleted and recreated with the same value.

```
r = Node(0)
for i in range(4):
    r=insert(r,i+1)
```

gives

```
new 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d1b240>
new 1 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e2e8>
new 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e390>
del 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d1b240>
new 2 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d1b240>
new 1 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e3c8>
new 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e358>
del 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e390>
del 1 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e2e8>
new 3 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e390>
new 2 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e320>
new 1 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e470>
new 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e2b0>
del 0 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e358>
del 1 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d2e3c8>
del 2 <Node object at 0x7f6dc2d1b240>
```

so any other variable referencing a node or even the root node will possibly reference something old.